# Проблема с размьютом (unmute time-out)

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord, disnake

Я доделал команду размьют но теперь у меня возникает ошибка с причиной. когда пишешь

> размьют <@username> <причина>

> размьют <@username>

Всегда отвечает "✅ @username был размьючен(а) по причине: None." Хотя я указывал в коде где нужно вставить причину а где нет. Внизу будут скриншот как работает команда в данный момент. Помогите пожайлуста. Заранее большое спасибо

```
@bot.command(aliases=["Размьют"])
async def размьют(ctx, member: disnake.Member = None, time=None, *, reason=None):
    if not ctx.author.guild_permissions.kick_members:
        embed = disnake.Embed(description=f"❌ У вас недостаточно прав на размьют!", color=0xc80005)
        return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    if not member:
        embed = disnake.Embed(description="❌ Вы не указали кому нужно снять мьют.", color=0xc80005)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return
    if member.current_timeout:
        await member.timeout(duration=None)
        if reason != None:
            embed = disnake.Embed(description=f"✅ **{member.display_name}** был размьючен(а).", color=0xc80005)
            await member.send(f"Модератор {ctx.author.mention} размьютил Вас на сервере **{ctx.guild.name}**.")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed = disnake.Embed(description=f"✅ **{member.display_name}** был размьючен(а) по причине: {reason}.", color=0xc80005)
            await member.send(f"Модератор {ctx.author.mention} размьютил Вас на сервере **{ctx.guild.name}** по причине: {reason}.")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = disnake.Embed(description=f"❌ **{member.display_name}** не имеет мьют.", color=0xc80005)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кароче я не правильно указал где должна быть причина и перепутал сообщения бота. В общем вот правильный ответ

```
@bot.command(aliases=["Размьют"])
async def размьют(ctx, member: disnake.Member = None, *, reason=None):
    if not ctx.author.guild_permissions.kick_members:
        embed = disnake.Embed(description=f"❌ У вас недостаточно прав на размьют!", color=0xc80005)
        return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    if not member:
        embed = disnake.Embed(description="❌ Вы не указали кому нужно снять мьют.", color=0xc80005)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return
    if member.current_timeout:
        await member.timeout(duration=None)
        if reason:
            embed = disnake.Embed(description=f"✅ **{member.display_name}** был размьючен(а) по причине: {reason}.", color=0xc80005)
            await member.send(f"Модератор {ctx.author.mention} размьютил Вас на сервере **{ctx.guild.name}** по причине: {reason}.")
        else:
            embed = disnake.Embed(description=f"✅ **{member.display_name}** был размьючен(а).", color=0xc80005)
            await member.send(f"Модератор {ctx.author.mention} размьютил Вас на сервере **{ctx.guild.name}**.")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = disnake.Embed(description=f"❌ **{member.display_name}** не имеет мьют.", color=0xc80005)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Я не могу принять свой ответ по этому мне нужно ждать 2 дня. Всем удачи! И спасибо тем кто хотел помоч.